# Drawing different kind of objects in the same selectAll function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I use the following code to draw my tooltip texts in a radial chart:

```
 var tooltip=settings.g.selectAll(".ticklabel")
                 .data(ticks)
                 .join(
                     enter => enter.append("text")
                         .style('display', 'none')
                         .attr("class", "ticklabel")
                         .attr("x", settings.width / 2 + 5)
                         .attr("y", d => settings.height / 2 - radialScale(d))
                         .attr('font-family', settings.fontFamily)
                         .attr('font-size', settings.fontSize - 2)
                         .text(d => getTickLabel(d))
                     )

//SOMETHING like that? This does nothing
.join(   enter => enter.append("rectangle")
                    .attr("x", settings.width / 2 + 5)
                    .attr("y", d => settings.height / 2 - radialScale(d))
                    .attr("width", 80)
                    .attr("height", 90)
                    .attr("fill", "black")
                    .style('display', 'none')  
)
```

To have a background, I need to place a rectangle behind each label. However, I cannot figure out whether it is possible to extend the following code so that it still uses the data (ticks) and draws rectangles, as needed. I would like to then have it in object "tooltip".

I tried another .join but that does not work.